# Can't seem to split list in panda series?

Tags: python, pandas, split, series

I have a column that contains multiple genres, I am trying to split the list of genres in order to get each genre separately however, whatever I try I keep getting NaN for the entire column in the data frame.

This is what the data looks like:

```
0                                      [Drama,, Romance]
1                 [Animation,, Comedy,, Kids, &, Family]
2                         [Drama,, Mystery, &, Suspense]
3                                                [Drama]
4                                                    NaN
5                 [Art, House, &, International,, Drama]
6       [Art, House, &, International,, Drama,, Romance]
7                                          [Documentary]
8      [Action, &, Adventure,, Animation,, Art, House...
9               [Action, &, Adventure,, Drama,, Western]
10                                     [Comedy,, Horror]
```

I am trying to get : 
["Drama", "Romance"]
["Animation", "Comedy","Kids & Family"] ...

I'm doing this because I want to be able to see how many unique genres there are, at the moment I can only see the unique lists but I want each unique genre.
I'm not even sure if I am going about this the right way so any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my latest try: 
(x is equal to the data shown plus more rows)

```
 x = pd.Series(x)
 x = x.str.split()
 [i.str.split() for i in x]
```

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Please post input data and desired output.

Comment: Can you also add what you're desired end dataframe looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Your data seems malformed with some extraneous commas.  Assuming your data are actually `string`s, you'll need to `eval` the `string` representation of a list into an actual `list`.

A few steps:

```
# First, import ast to use for literal_eval()
import ast

# Then, remove the extraneous commas
new_df = df[0].str.replace(', ',' ')

# Then, add quotes into your listed items to prep for eval.
new_df = new_df.str.replace(r'(?P<item>\b[\w &]+)',r'"\1"')

# Then, eval the string representation
lst = [ast.literal_eval(i) for i in new_df if pd.notnull(i)]

# Or, you can just put all of this together:
lst = [ast.literal_eval(i) for i in df[0].str.replace(', ',' ').str.replace(r'(?P<item>\b[\w &]+)',r'"\1"') if pd.notnull(i)]
```

**Output:**

```
[['Drama', 'Romance'],
 ['Animation', 'Comedy', 'Kids & Family'],
 ['Drama', 'Mystery & Suspense'],
 ['Drama'],
 ['Art House & International', 'Drama'],
 ['Art House & International', 'Drama', 'Romance'],
 ['Documentary'],
 ['Action & Adventure', 'Animation', 'Art House'],
 ['Action & Adventure', 'Drama', 'Western'],
 ['Comedy', 'Horror']]
```

If you want the index and represent it as a dictionary:

```
 d = {i: ast.literal_eval(j) for i, j in new_df.items() if pd.notnull(j)}
```

**Output:**

```
{0: ['Drama', 'Romance'],
 1: ['Animation', 'Comedy', 'Kids & Family'],
 2: ['Drama', 'Mystery & Suspense'],
 3: ['Drama'],
 5: ['Art House & International', 'Drama'],
 6: ['Art House & International', 'Drama', 'Romance'],
 7: ['Documentary'],
 8: ['Action & Adventure', 'Animation', 'Art House'],
 9: ['Action & Adventure', 'Drama', 'Western'],
 10: ['Comedy', 'Horror']}
```

If you wanted it in a `DataFrame` though, I'm not sure how you want that represented, but once you have the `dict` or `list` it's trivial to revert back.

Comment: What is it producing? If it was an error, what kind of error are you getting? Is your data already an array or is it actually strings?